# Magento Ingestion with Junglee

Tags: magento

How do you integrate Magento with Jungle?

I have heard that you would need to create user permissions for Jungle, however, i am not too sure how Jungle would access by Magento panel and extract data. Can anyone help with more info?

Comment: This question is very broad. StackOverflow can only really assist with specific roadblocks you're encountering with programs you've written. It helps if you have code with a specific question that you need assistance with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a soap user with just catalog view/edit permissions. And I think you also need to create product XML feeds. Its better to approach junglee tech support team for more details.